# Is there a table that includes all of the magic items sorted by rarity?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, treasure

This might be a 'read the rules' to me question, but I haven't been able to find it.

I need to select a magic item based on it's rarity (specifically Uncommon if it's relevant). I'm looking for a table that lists all of the DMG's magical items alphabetically and either splits them by rarity or indicates rarity. This seems like a very useful table for a DM to dole out treasure from, so I'm not sure why it would be excluded.

Without this table, I've had to sort through the entire list of magic items manually and check rarity, which isn't a big ordeal, but it is inconvenient.

Is there a table like this available somewhere? I know that sometimes useful tables that reasonably belong in one book end up being put in another.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the resources at [Donjon](http://donjon.bin.sh/5e/magic_items/) rather handy. You can sort by rarity, type and need for attunement.